# adding my own jar file as javaagent on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to make a custom buildpack on bluemix, as part of it I am trying to add my own jar file as a javaagent. I used to work with Tomcat where I just added the extra agent to the `catalina.sh` script.

On bluemix those are the steps I took:

1. I create new project and uploaded my code.
2. I cloned the default java buildpack to my own git repository.
3. On the repository I added the .jar file on /lib/java_buildpack folder.
4. Now is the step I have trouble with, I located the:

   ```
   java_opts.add_javaagent(@droplet.sandbox + 'javaagent.jar')
   ```

   function call which according to the comments should so exactly what I am looking for.

the issue is that when I check the function I see that it calls the following function:

```
qualify_path(path, root = @droplet_root)
"$PWD/#{path.relative_path_from(root)}"
```

I cant figure out where is this @droplet_root position is, if I could find it I could upload my jar file there.

I tried adding the relative position like this:

```
java_opts << "java_buildpack/myAgent.jar"
```

But it didnt work.

Any suggestions on how it might be achieved? where should I place the file or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Forking the buildpack is one way to achieve this. You can implement this as a "framework" in the Java buildpack. Here are a few samples you can refer to which also adds an agent jar:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/lib/java_buildpack/framework/new_relic_agent.rb

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/lib/java_buildpack/framework/jrebel_agent.rb

Another little hacky way is to simply add the agent jar to your application package, and then add a Java option to enable the agent, using the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. That requires you to find out the path where the agent jar ends up in the running application container. You can browse to it by using "cf files". This will have a dependency on the internal structure of the droplet so it may get broken if the buildpack changes the droplet structure.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, I opened the examples and from what I see they used the way you specified on the end. its what I try to do but it doesnt work, I placed my jar file at lib/java_buildpack/file.jar and tried adding it in the new_relic_agent.rb file inside the framework library in the following manner: adding the line: `.add_javaagent(@droplet.sandbox + 'lib/java_buildpack/gbAgent.jar')`. but it doesnt seem to work. How can I check if the javaagent was updated or not? (check if its a path problem or working problem)

Comment: The difference between the first option and the second is that the second one does not need to change the buildpack code at all. The JAVA_OPTS is an application environment variable that you can set using "cf set-env". To make this first approach work, you need to look into the below code as well:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/lib/java_buildpack/component/versioned_dependency_component.rb which is inherited by the new_relic and jrebel agent. And you need a configuration file like https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/config/new_relic_agent.yml